# the ishvara paradox

Tags: vishnu, buddha

If buddha is the incarnation of Visnu, like *sanatana (hindu) religion* believe, do we have something of a dilemma?  what are we to say, he was just fake suffering before his enlightenment?  c'mon, that is not going to hold over well. we need a better idea.  i know scripture is above my level, so please answer with your good bodhi.

Comment: Sir please actually google Vishnu's Buddha we don't accept faulty Buddhist literature on our lord.

Answer (score 2):

Lord Buddha as an avatar of Lord Vishnu from Sanatana text.:

> *“tataḥ kalau sampravṛtte sammohāya sura-dviṣām | buddho nāmnāñjana-sutaḥ kīkaṭeṣu bhaviṣyati ||” (SB 1:3:24).*
>
> *“Then, in the beginning of Kali-yuga, the Lord (Vishnu) will appear as Lord Buddha, the son of Añjanā, in the province of Gayā, just for the purpose of deluding those who are envious of the faithful theist”.*

Lord Buddha as an avatar of Lord Vishnu from Buddhist text.:

[Dashrath Jataka](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/j4/j4025.htm).:

> *"At that time the king Suddhodana 3 was king Dasaratha, Mahāmāyā 3 was the mother, Rāhulā's mother 4 was Sītā, Ānanda was Bharata, and **I (Buddha) myself was Rāma-paṇḍita. "***

[Lalitavistara chapter 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjt7r.png).

As for the struggles, Lord Vishnu always suffers n do struggle in his avataras to set an example for mankind.

**Srimad Devi Bhagwatam 5.1.:**

> *12-54. Vyāsa said :-- “True it has been said by you that Vāsudeva the Janārdana, is the destroyer of the Daityas and He is able to create and preserve the Devas and do all other acts for them. But the Great Lord assumed a human body; therefore he had to perform his duties like a man and observe the Varṇa and Āśrama Dharmas pertaining to human beings. Respecting the elderly persons, worshipping the spiritual teachers, doing service to the Brahmāṇas, adoring and propitiating the Devas, feeling sorrow at times of sorrow, feeling pleasure at times of happiness,…”*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..